# Handling corrupted archives in python

Tags: python, tar

I have a file compression/decompression system where I first check if the file is compressed or not, if not then I compress this file into a tar archive (tar.gz). Then the compressed archive is uploaded to a server. After uploading, the server decompresses the file and some processing is done on this file.

The problem arises if the compression service shuts down during compressing of a file. As a result the tar archive gets corrupted.

```
....
tar = tarfile.open(compress_file_name, "w:gz")
tar.add(file_path, arcname=file_name)
tar.close()
....
```

And to verify integrity of the file I try

```
try:
    f = tarfile.open(file_path) # This should throw CRC error but its not
except Exception, e:
    raise e
```

But In-fact python seems to open the file just fine. To verify whether the file is really ok or not, I tried to open the file `tar -xvzf <corrupted_archive>` and I got

```
[~/]$ tar -xvzf <corrupted_archive>

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Now I can use this same process in python using `subprocess.call(['tar','-xvzf',archive_name])` but I actually what a pythonic method to verify the integrity of the file.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opening the file will not produce any error unless the header is corrupt. You need to read the whole file in order to reveal errors. Doesn't matter that this is a tar.gz, the CRC from the GZIP (.gz) part will be enough to (hopefully) reveal errors:

```
import gzip

with gzip.open(file_path) as g:
    try:
        while g.read(1024 * 1024):
            pass
    except IOError as e:
        print("Corrupted!", e)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its working as expected. Can I ask that as I understand, will `g.read()` be reading the entire file in memory ? What if I have a large archive (lets say a 20GB corrputed archive).

Comment: No, it will read and discard it. If you have a large archive, it will take some time, but memory usage will not change.

Comment: Nope, `g.read()` will read the whole file in memory, **then** discard, thus you will have problems

Comment: Good luck with this if your file is anything large.

Comment: thus you would want to do `while g.read(2 ** 20): pass`. This is the easiest fix, as it will make sure that the gzip stream is not abruptly ended.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala fair enough. This edited version will read in chunks of 1MiB, eliminating the problem. You can adjust the `1024 * 1024` (1MiB) if you wish. The higher the faster, but the memory footprint will be bigger.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Yes I was getting `MemoryError` with the code you shared. But the edited code snippet with chunk size as 1MB seems to be working fine. Slow, yes, but right now speed is the least of my concern.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you for your feedback on the memory problem

Comment: If you are working on modern hardware, you can increase chunk size to 100MiB or so. It might be faster. Experiment a bit.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I tried this technique on a number of archives, the success ratio was about 80%, still there were some corrupted archives that unix tar wasn't able to extract but python gzip was reading them just fine. I just had to go with the unix tar method to determine the integrity of the archive. Seems like there isn't any reliable pythonic method yet. Upvoted.

Comment: Unfortunately, TAr and GZIP cannot detect all corruptions. It might happen that a corrupt GZIP archive has the right CRC checksum. It might even happen that a corrupted TAr archive extracts without a single error or warning. This is why a strong checksum (usually SHA) is often provided together with the tarfile. More modern containers, such as XZ, embed a SHA checksum for better integrity check.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo You are absolutely right. I had to re-design the flow for handling these archives.